# Connecting two "makes" together: can I leave one out?

Tags: conjunctions

Must I repeat the same word twice if the meanings or usages are different? For example, conjugating the following two sentences is easy.

> I make donuts. + I make muffins. = I make donuts and muffins.

Then is this valid?

> I make robots. + I make them move. = I make robots and them move.

I intuit that “I make robots and make them move.” is better if not paraphrase, but want to revisit the reason again in a more general way. Thanks for your reading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the issue here is that *make* is two different verbs in your second sentence, or at least has two distinct meanings.

> I make robots = I manufacture robots.
>   I make them move = I force them to move.

Consequently you have to repeat the verb, just as you would if you were to use the equivalents:

> I manufacture robots and force them to move.

In your first sentence, both instances of *make* mean *manufacture,* so you don't have to repeat the verb.

The answer is yes: you do have to repeat it if the sense is different.

Comment: I would argue that the problem isn't with *make*, it's with *move*. *Robots* is a noun but *move* is a verb. The following would be fine without repeating *make*: *I make robots and their movement*. If you're going to mix a noun and a verb, you need to repeat the initial verb. If I followed your argument I could not combine *I made robots* + *I made a move* into *I made robots and a move*. But I believe that's possible (although not normal) because both *robots* and *a move* are nouns. In that example, *made* takes on different senses by the end of the sentence.

Comment: It's an example of _syllepsis_ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeugma_and_syllepsis

Comment: @JasonB I disagree profoundly with your comment. Neither of what you suggest as possible is possible.

Comment: @AndrewLeach It happens in writing, it's accepted as a literary device, and it's understandable. (If the link in the comment above hadn't been posted, I would have posted it myself.)